# Elliptic Regularity on Manifolds

Tags: partial-differential-equations, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

Sorry if this has been asked before.

Are there are books which talk about elliptic regularity on manifolds? Everything I've been able to find has been about $\mathbb{R}^n$. Can every question about regularity on a manifold be reduced to regularity on $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Chapter 6 of Warner (*Foundations of Differentiable Manifolds and Lie Groups*) covers elliptic operators on manifolds. Specifically, you're probably interested in Theorem 6.5 and its proof in 6.32. The proof uses coordinate charts and elliptic regularity in $\mathbb{R}^n$ to establish smooth local solutions and then pieces the global solution together with a partition of unity.

You may also be interested in Booss-Bleeker (*Topology and Analysis: The Atiyah-Singer Index Formula and Gauge-Theoretic Physics*). Additionally, [here](http://www.indiana.edu/~jfdavis/teaching/m721/Elliptic_Regularity.pdf) is a sketch of some of the ideas from a course at Indiana University several years ago.